# Why does the application force close on adding an image at the background in Relative layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, background, android-activity

the activities in my application were working normally until I added a background to the layout. My app just force closes.Here is my manifest file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/black5" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addsubtask" />

    <RelativeLayout />

    <LinearLayout />
```

I get the following errors. I have no idea what they are. The Force close occurs only on adding a background image. Please suggest me how to fix this.

```
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smacon.task/com.smacon.task.Add_task}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at com.smacon.task.Add_task.onCreate(Add_task.java:62)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    ... 11 more
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    ... 24 more
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
 03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
  03-03 06:04:30.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1470):   ... 27 more
```

Comment: could be out of memory exception. post the stack trace

Comment: it is out of memory error..,means you have not enough space

Comment: scaled down your image `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` confirms that

Comment: and 1 thing...,change your xml code

Comment: change this two lines at the end in your layout..      </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>